# How do i zip files in python without all directories written to it

Tags: python, directory, zip

Im trying to zip multible files but i have run into a strange problem when i opened the zip file all directories leading to the files are listed as well
`home/site/Uploads/test/`

Here is the python code i have written

```
import os
import zipfile

zf = zipfile.ZipFile("myzipfile.zip", "w")
for dirname, subdirs, files in os.walk("D:/home/site/Uploads/test/"):
zf.write(dirname)
for filename in files:
    zf.write(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
zf.close()
```

The zipped files are fine but why is every other directory listed too.

I got the zip file like this
-->home-->site-->Uploads-->test-->file.txt
what i wanted was this
-->file.txt

Comment: That's the default. You might want to `zf.write(os.path.join(dirname, filename), arcname=filename)`

Comment: Thank you but now i have another problem the directories are still listed like this file.txt file2.txt home

Comment: Please edit your question, show the output/zip structure you got and what you expect to get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets assume the following directory structure:

```
./uploads
└── foo
    └── bar
        ├── 1.txt
        └── baz
            └── 2.txt
```

You just need to set the arcname correct:

```
import os
import zipfile

zf = zipfile.ZipFile("myzipfile.zip", "w")
for dirname, subdirs, files in os.walk("/tmp/uploads"):
    for filename in files:
        zf.write(os.path.join(dirname, filename), arcname=filename)
zf.close()
```

Unzip shows the zip file like this:

```
unzip -l myzipfile.zip                                                                                                                    Archive:  myzipfile.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  10-21-2019 15:03   1.txt
        0  10-21-2019 15:03   2.txt
---------                     -------
        0                     2 files
```